# Using classes in any type of programming?

Tags: html, class

In html programming, do websites require classes even if some websites don't require or don't contain java script? Is it OK to not need standard classes in an html file or does every website that is on the internet uses some sort of class within their html?

Comment: By calling it "classes", do you mean those of programming languages(Java, c++) or is it from HTML's 'class' attribute?

Comment: programming c++ or java, not talking about the class attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classes in HTML are very useful, particularly in CSS. If you want to create a design for your web page which you can use more than once, you can use the same CSS stylesheet for multiple pages, and each page will contain the same classes referenced by the CSS stylesheet. Moreover, if you want two elements of the same type in HTML to look different, you would make a class for each one and reference each class in your CSS stylesheet.

There is a good read [here](https://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/) which explains why you should use classes in HTML.

EDIT: Reading the other comments, it seems that OP didn't mean class attributes in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Class are not required but they are great for adding css or targeting specific elements with javascript/jQuery. Pretty much every website will use classes in HTML code.

I am referring to the class attribute not a (C++, Java) class.

Comment: LOL... somebody has to correct the tags for the question.

Comment: I don't have any reputation so I can't do anything accept answer questions

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of either JavaScript or HTML making use of "Class" from the programming languages. They don't need any such programming language's(Java, C++) Classes.